# Find a single element within an array without looping through the array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array with objects stored within it. I want to grab the object in the array that has a name of test-song-poll-02. I know I could loop thru it and do a conditional to check the name within each object but I was wondering if there is an array/object php function that can return the object where name = 'test-song-poll-03'

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test-song-poll-01
            [description] => test-song-poll-01
            [created_at] => 2014-05-02T23:07:59Z
            [count] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [approved] => 63787
                    [pending] => 341
                    [rejected] => 78962
                    [total] => 143090
                )

            [tpm] => 12
            [approved_tpm] => 3
            [pct] => 4
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test-song-poll-02
            [description] => test-song-poll-02
            [created_at] => 2014-05-02T23:17:20Z
            [count] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [approved] => 9587
                    [pending] => 0
                    [rejected] => 9780
                    [total] => 19367
                )

            [tpm] => 5
            [approved_tpm] => 3
            [pct] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test-song-poll-03
            [description] => test-song-poll-03
            [created_at] => 2014-05-02T23:19:06Z
            [count] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [approved] => 26442
                    [pending] => 0
                    [rejected] => 36242
                    [total] => 62684
                )

            [tpm] => 25
            [approved_tpm] => 9
            [pct] => 2
        )
)
```

UPDATED my code to show how I want to pass a variable in:

```
function get_results()
{
    $hashtag = "test-song-poll-03";
    $this->load->model('artist_model');
    $data['results'] = $this->artist_model->get_results();

    $myobject = array_filter($data['results']->streams, function($e, $hashtag) {
      return strcmp($e->name, $hashtag) == 0;
    });

    print_r($myobject);
}
```

Comment: Do you have control over how the array is constructed?

Comment: No, I am pulling json data from an api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_filter.

```
$myobjects = array_filter($objects, function($e) use($hashtag) {
  return strcmp($e->name, "test-song-poll-03") == 0;
});
```

Because of the anonymous function, this will only work PHP >= 5.3

You can use your own function if you have older version.

Comment: Can you make the "test-song-poll-03" a variable to be passed in there? I tried passing it as parameter in the function where you pass $e but it gave me an error: Warning: Missing argument 2 for Home::{closure}() in and Notice: Undefined variable: hashtag in. The variable I am trying to pass is $hashtag. I updated the code to show you how I am using your code.

Comment: I have no idea about that, but you can try it with 'global $hashtag;' maybe. Gonna test it.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can use 'use($hashtag)' for passing variables into the closure.

Comment: That code is slightly misleading, it returns an array, not a single object. This array contains all(!) objects with the according name, but there can be zero or multiple such values, too. Other than that, it doesn't avoid looping through the array, which can be computationally expensive. If that is important, you need an array that maps from the searched name to the according object (or objects?), similar to a database index.

Comment: He is pulling the data from an API, can't change the array, so no other way.

Comment: This is going to loop through the entire array even if it finds a match in the first iteration? With a foreach loop you could bail as soon as you find a match. I'm not convinced this is your best option.

Comment: You are true vascowhite, the OP didn't ask the BEST option, he was asking for a function within PHP. If you reread his question you can see.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are getting your data from an API in json format does not mean that you have to keep it in the format you are given. There are several strategies that will be more efficient than your accepted answer.

The issue with the currently selected answer is that it will iterate over the full data set every time you use it, even if a match is found on the first iteration. I don't know how big your dataset is, but I'm assuming it is significant otherwise you wouldn't have been asking this question.

I also don't know how many times you want to access the dataset, you probably don't either, but I assume it is enough times to make you think about or, again, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Lets assume that you have a dataset that consists of 1000 of your `stdClass` objects and that you ask for each of those objects once, so you access it 1000 times.

Now the 'array_filter()' method that has been suggested to you has to access all 1000 elements (it is O(n)) every time, that is a total of 1,000,000 iterations.

```
//Access every element once using array_filter()
$objectArray = [];
$objectNames = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i ++){
    $objName = 'object_name_' . ($i + 1);
    $objectNames[] = $objName;
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->name = $objName;
    $obj->description = 'test description';
    $obj->accessed = 0;
    $objectArray[] = $obj;
}
$start = microtime(true);
foreach($objectNames as $name){
    $iterations = getObjectWithArray_Filter($name, $objectArray);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$taken = $end - $start;
echo $iterations . " iterations using array_filter() in $taken seconds<br/>\n";
```

[see it working](http://3v4l.org/DWDvB).

The first alternative that comes to mind is a plain old `foreach()`loop, this is also O(n), but the loop can be written to bail as soon as it finds a match. So, assuming we access each element of the array once we will have 500,500 iterations, a saving of around 50%. This may or may not apply in the real world, you will be the best judge of that.

```
//Access every element once using foreach(){}
$objectArray = [];
$objectNames = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i ++){
    $objName = 'object_name_' . ($i + 1);
    $objectNames[] = $objName;
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->name = $objName;
    $obj->description = 'test description';
    $obj->accessed = 0;
    $objectArray[] = $obj;
}

$start = microtime(true);
foreach($objectNames as $name){
    $iterations = getObjectWithForeach($name, $objectArray);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$taken = $end - $start;
echo $iterations . " iterations using foreach(){} in $taken seconds<br/>\n";
```

[see it working](http://3v4l.org/DWDvB).

The second alternative that occurs to me is to run through the array once and write it out to an associative array. The first run through will be O(n), 1000 iterations and thereafter we will be able to access the element we want directly without iterating through the array at all, which is O(1). Giving us 2000 iterations for accessing every element of the array once.

```
//Access every element once using Associative array
$objectArray = [];
$objectNames = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i ++){
    $objName = 'object_name_' . ($i + 1);
    $objectNames[] = $objName;
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->name = $objName;
    $obj->description = 'test description';
    $obj->accessed = 0;
    $objectArray[] = $obj;
}

$associativeArray = [];
$start = microtime(true);
foreach($objectArray as $object){
    $associativeArray[$object->name] = $object;
    $object->accessed ++;
}

foreach($objectNames as $name){
    $iterations = getObjectFromAssociativeArray($objName, $associativeArray);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$taken = $end - $start;
echo $iterations . " iterations using associative array{} in $taken seconds<br/>\n";
```

[see it working](http://3v4l.org/DWDvB).

Here is the rest of my test code:-

```
//=================================================================
function getObjectWithArray_Filter($objectName, array $objectArray){
    $myobjects = array_filter($objectArray, function($e) use($objectName) {
            $e->accessed ++;
            return strcmp($e->name, $objectName) == 0;
        });
    $iterations = 0;
    foreach($objectArray as $object){
        $iterations += $object->accessed;
    }
    return $iterations;
}

function getObjectWithForeach($objectName, array $objectArray){
    $iterations = 0;
    $found = false;
    $count = 0;
    while(!$found){
        $objectArray[$count]->accessed ++;
        if($objectArray[$count]->name === $objectName){
            $found = true;
        }
        $count ++;
    }
    foreach($objectArray as $object){
        $iterations += $object->accessed;
    }
    return $iterations;
}

function getObjectFromAssociativeArray($objectName, array $objectArray){
    $iterations = 0;
    if($objectName === $objectArray[$objectName]->name){
        $objectArray[$objectName]->accessed ++;
    }
    foreach($objectArray as $object){
        $iterations += $object->accessed;
    }
    return $iterations;
}
```

**tl;dr**
Output on 3v4l.org:-

```
Accessing 1000 elements once took 1000000 iterations using array_filter() in 0.5374710559845 seconds
Accessing 1000 elements once took 500500 iterations using foreach(){} in 0.2077169418335 seconds
Accessing 1000 elements once took 2000 iterations using associative array{} in 0.1438410282135 seconds
```

[see it working](http://3v4l.org/DWDvB).

The timing differences are interesting too. You may or may not need to optimise for speed like this, but I would suggest that this is a worthwhile change to make to your code. In any case I would think that no iterations after the first is much better than 1000 or an average of 500.5 every time.

I hope you see this as a worthwhile exercise, your question piqued my interest and I was convinced that the answer you accepted was not the best solution for you. You may still think it is, but I offer this as an alternative.

The simplest way of implementing this would be to use some kind of object store/factory:-

```
class ObjectStore
{
    private $decoded;
    private $asssocArray;

    public function __construct($jsonEncodedObjects)
    {
        $this->decoded = json_decode($jsonEncodedObjects);
    }

    public function getObject($objectName)
    {
        if(!$this->asssocArray){
            foreach($this->decoded as $object){
                $this->asssocArray[$object->name] = $object;
            }
        }
        return $this->asssocArray[$objectName];
    }
}
```

This way your first request for an object is O(n) and subsequent requests will be O(1).

To use this with your code:-

```
$objectStore = new ObjectStore(getJsonEncodedData());

$hashtag = "test-song-poll-03";
$myObject = $objectStore->getObject($hashtag);
```

Comment: You are true, the OP didn't ask the BEST option, he was asking for a function within PHP. If you reread his question you can see.

Comment: @newboyhun What people ask for isn't always what they need, your solution isn't a bad one, just not suited to this instance. It is causing the OP [further problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23460695/212940).