# strip array with only one item in it without looping thru it and not knowing its index

Tags: php, arrays, object

```
Array
(
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => test-song-poll-03
            [description] => test-song-poll-03
            [created_at] => 2014-05-02T23:19:06Z
            [count] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [approved] => 26638
                    [pending] => 0
                    [rejected] => 36923
                    [total] => 63561
                )

            [tpm] => 47
            [approved_tpm] => 9
            [pct] => 2
        )

)
```

I have a function that uses array_filter and it returns what you see above. It will only return one object within the array. I do not know what the array index will be, but I know there will only be one item in the array. Is there an array function that strips down the array and just returns the content of it, since I don't need an array with just one item in it.

Comment: `$x = array_pop($myFilteredArray);`

Comment: You have this problem because the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23460493/212940) to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23460416/212940) is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
$x = array_values($yourArrayName);
echo $x[0];
```

You can also use:

```
echo current($yourArrayName);
```